# Stabiliser a Conic

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space, projection-matrices

I am trying to solve: Consider the conic $C = Z(X_{0}X_{1} - X_{2}^{2})$ in the projective plane.

(a) Find the pointwise stabiliser of $C$ in $PGL(3,K)$

(b) Find the setwise stabiliser of $C$ in $PGL(3,K)$

My attempt:

**Step1:** I try to find the points in $C$ as follows:

We have two cases to consider:

Case1: $X_{0} = 0$. In this case, we must have $X_{2} = 0$, then we just have one point on the conic of the form $(0,a,b)$ which is $(0,1,0)$.

Case2: $X_{0} \neq 0$. In this case, we have all the points of the form $(1,a,a^{2})$ where a is any element of $K$, including $0$.

**Step2:**

Then, I take any 3 x 3 matrix, right now, I have no idea about the entries of the matrix. Since we are looking for the pointwise stabiliser of the conic, our matrix must map $[0,1,0]$ to itself. This means that, the second column of the matrix must be $[0,\lambda,0]$ for some nonzero $\lambda$ in $K$.

If we apply the same reasoning to $[1,0,0]$, then the first column of the matrix must be $[\beta,0,0]$.

Since our matrix, must be invertible, the last row cannot be $[0,0,0]$ thus it is of the form $[0,0,\alpha]$ for some nonzero $\alpha$ in $K$. Since, we are working with projectivities, we can normalize the last row to $[0,0,1]$. Now, our matrix looks like:
\begin{bmatrix}
\beta & 0 & *\\
0 & \lambda & *\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
where * is any element of $K$, including $0$. I came here so far.

My main question is how to solve such questions in general: We are given an object in projective space, not necessarily zero locus of a linear form. How to find its pointwise and setwise stabiliser in projectivity group? Is there an algorithm to do this?

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: And surely the $*$s are $1-\beta$ and $1-\lambda$?

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thank you very much for pointing my typo, it should be $PGL(3,K)$ .  Actually, my main point is not to solve this question, rather trying to come up with an algorithm or a general method which solves such questions. Is my method true or reasonable? Secondly, how one should attack such a question? Thirdly, what about setwise stabiliser? Thanks, again.

Comment: In this particular case I think your strategy is right. With my comment above we can see that the point stabiliser is a certain subgroup isomorphic to $K^*\times K^*$. The point-stabiliser will be a normal subgroup of the set-stabiliser, which may help. Won't the quotient be a $PGL(2,K)$? [I seem to remember that conics are just projective lines.] So I believe that in this case you could crunch out the answer. In general all I can see is that the set-stabiliser contains as a normal subgroup the point-stabiliser.